# Memory leak in Creating Direct2D Device

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, directx-11, direct2d, dxgi

For testing purposes, I put the code into a for loop which creates and releases one thousand Direct2D devices but it never free up the allocated memory:

```
for (UINT i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    hr = m_lpD2DFactory->CreateDevice(lpDxgiDevice, &m_lpD2DDevice);
    m_lpD2DDevice->Release();
}
```

Execution of the code above holds around 500MB of memory. Seems like releasing the device has no effect.

I appreciate any help.

**Update**

I have found out that if I uncomment rest of my code which leads to a pair of calls to [ID2DRenderTarget::BeginDraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371768(v=vs.85).aspx) and [ID2DRenderTarget::EndDraw](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371924(v=vs.85).aspx) using the created device, the `Release` method works as expected. It is still strange and could be problem if somehow my code does not lead to those calls.

```
hr = m_lpD2DFactory->CreateDevice(lpDxgiDevice, &m_lpD2DDevice);
...
lpRenderTarget->BeginDraw();    
lpRenderTarget->EndDraw();
...
m_lpD2DDevice->Release();
```

Comment: Have you tried calling [`m_lpD2DDevice->ClearResources()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404542.aspx) before calling `Release()`?  Maybe it won't make a difference. What is the return value of `Release()`? Ideally, it should always be 0 in your example.

Comment: @Remy Thanks for the response. I tried ClearResources and it didn't change anything. I also checked return value of Release and it is 0 as expected.

Comment: Short of a D2D driver bug, it sounds like maybe D2D is simply holding on to internal resources, probably caching them for later reuse.  Not unheard of in memory management systems, especially when allocating new resources dynamically may be slow/expensive.  Is there a reason why your tasks can't reuse devices?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I can reuse them but since the entire design is OO, I don't like to hold a static reference and having  Init, Shutdown pair functions in the program lifetime. However, check my update, looks like problem is somehow solved.